# Drawing pie segment percentage in middle of doughnut with chartjs issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to draw the percentage of the doughnut segment that is currently being hovered over in the middle of the doughnut.

I'm using chartjs 2 and so I'm looking into the plugins. It says [on the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) that one of the times a plugin can be called on "afterEvent" -  "When an event occurs on the canvas (mousemove, click, etc). This requires the options.events property handled". The code on the page is as follows:

```
afterEvent: function(chartInstance, event) {}
```

However, I'm not sure how to use the afterEvent state. I've got as far as drawing in the middle of the doughnut in a static fashion by following examples [such as this](https://jsfiddle.net/g733tj8h/). But I want to be able to run this code on 'afterEvent' instead of 'beforeDraw'. Is there any documentation as to what event data comes in the 'event' parameter? If it is a hover event, will it give me the value of the segment that is being hovered in the same way 'onHover' does?

I just couldn't find any further documentation anywhere. It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely possible to implement this via plugins, but here is an alternative approach that gives you the exact same behavior.

Basically, you use an external custom tooltip positioned in the middle of the chart that is triggered when a chart segment is hovered.

Here is the relevant code

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.custom = function(tooltip) {
  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var total = 0;

    // get the value of the datapoint
    var value = this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data[tooltip.dataPoints[0].index].toLocaleString();

    // calculate value of all datapoints
  this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data.forEach(function(e) {
      total += e;
    });

    // calculate percentage and set tooltip value
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<h1>' + (value / total * 100) + '%</h1>';
  }

  // calculate position of tooltip
  var centerX = (this._chartInstance.chartArea.left + this._chartInstance.chartArea.right) / 2;
  var centerY = ((this._chartInstance.chartArea.top + this._chartInstance.chartArea.bottom) / 2);

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = centerX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = centerY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._fontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.fontSize;
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._fontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};
```

And a [working example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/vxNRmW) as well.

Comment: Ah that's great, I didn't think to use the custom tooltip approach. That's exactly what I'm looking for, and has the benefit of being styled with CSS rather than on the canvas. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I've ran into a problem now that I've tried to implement it with my own chart. For some reason tooltip.dataPoints doesn't exist. I've done Inspect Element and put a breakpoint on that line and when I look at what the tooltip object contains, dataPoints isn't there. Is there some setting I've failed to turn on or something like that? My code and your code look identical - other than the fact my chart data gets updated during use (as in I do an update() after poiting "data" at a new array of datapoints), could that be the problem?

Comment: Ignore the last comment, it turns out I was using chartjs 2.1 which doesn't have the datapoints attribute in tooltip. After I changed to 2.5 now it works perfectly, thanks again!